# How can I use a Modal Pop Up control in ASP.NET similar to a WinForms Message box?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-ajax, validation, messagebox

I am building a form, where required field validation must have been checked. I am not using asp validator. I am using JQuery validator like

function checkRequiredInputs(){

```
$("#frmSaleSubmissionInfo").validate({  
    rules:{
        txtFName:{required: true},
        txtLName:{required: true},
        txtAddress:{required: true},
        txtPhone:{required: true}
    },
    messages:{
        txtFName:"Enter Name",
        txtLName:"Enter Name",
        txtAddress:"Enter Address",
        txtPhone:"Enter Phone Number"
    }
});
```

This is my client side validation. I am using c# in my code behind page. Now if I turned off allowjavascript option in my browser, as far as I know it won't allow javascript. So I am also doing server-side validation for required field. But, since ASP.NET does not have a message-box control, I am having trouble to let the user know what field he is keeping empty. Is there any way to use a control like the message box to show or let the user know what field(s) is/are required to fill the form successfully?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my point of view, the best fitted to your requirement is using ASP.NET AJAX Toolkit [ValidatorCallout](http://www.asp.net/ajax/ajaxcontroltoolkit/Samples/ValidatorCallout/ValidatorCallout.aspx) control, which can help you to build such solution more fast way.

But if you don't want mixed up two javascript framework (ASP.NET AJAX and jQuery) than you can [be expired here](http://encosia.com/using-jquery-validation-with-asp-net-webforms/), where you can find a solution how to deal with a validation and jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a modal popup, just send some javascript from the server code:

```
Response.Write(
    "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('A required field is missing.');</script>");
```

`alert()` is a javascript function. `Response.Write()` adds the `<script>` element to the end of the HTTP response (i.e., the rendered HTML page).

A more elegant approach would be to use the ClientScriptManager to register a startup script:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    this.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this.GetType(), 
        "RequiredFieldValidationScript", 
        "alert('A required field is missing.');", 
        true);
}
```

The javascript code `alert('A required field is missing.');` will be executed after the postback.

See also: https://web.archive.org/web/20210417085026/https://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/021104-1.2.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Without javascript, I can't imagine a simple way of recreating a modal type popup.  You would have to go as to postback and re-render the page with a DIV blocking out the page and another div on top of it with the errors.

You can always pipe out the errors to a  tag next to the submit button and call it a day though.